# How to make a Http request POST with redirect to external website in PHP?

Tags: php, http, post, redirect

The situation I have is the following.

The user makes a payment on an external web gateway. This site sends my website (in PHP) payment data.
My PHP file receives this data and checks if it is necessary to refund the money to the user.

If so, the return order (with the necessary post data) is sent to the payment gateway as follows:

```
function enviarDevolucion($parametros, $firma, $urlDelEntorno){
    $data = [
        'Ds_SignatureVersion' => VERSION_FIRMA, 
        'Ds_MerchantParameters' => $parametros,
        'Ds_Signature' => $firma,
    ];

    registrarLogDePago('utils - enviarDevolucion | $parametros: '.json_encode($parametros).', $firma: '.$firma.', $urlDelEntorno: '.$urlDelEntorno);
    
    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($urlDelEntorno, false, $context);
    if ($result === FALSE) { 
        registrarLogDePago('(ERROR) utils - enviarDevolucion | Se ha producido un error al enviar la solicitud de devolucion');
    }
}
```

This works correctly.
However, this way I don't get a response from the payment gateway. I only get its web content.

To clarify, we send the payment gateway, in addition to the refund data, 2 URLs:

- URL_OK: The payment gateway will redirect if the return is ok
- URL_NO_OK: The payment gateway will redirect if the return has not been made
  The gateway will send details of the refund made or the error to the corresponding URL.

I would like to receive this data to save it in the DB and know if the refund has been made. Now I only know that I submitted the refund request but not if it was done.

Is there a way to send the data to the payment gateway in PHP so that it can redirect the user to the URL (URL OK or URL NO OK) automatically?

(We don't want to use js)

Comment: ___Unless I am missing something which is quite possible___ Make the OK and NOT OK Urls on your site, then you grab the info you want and then YOU forward whatever you want on to the user

Comment: I have created a file called dev.php on my website:
`<?php
error_log('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
?>`
Both URL_OK and URL_NO_OK point to it.
However, with my current code, the money has been refunded, but the payment gateway does not seem to execute my dev.php file.

I don't really know why.

Comment: This is starting to look like we need to know your payment gateway. Its not easy debugging remotely, its even more difficult when you are not sure what you are debugging

Comment: A few days ago I did another test: When I receive the data from the payment gateway in my php and verify that the money should be refunded to the user, I show an HTML error screen. In this HTMl I include a form that is sent to the payment gateway with jquery when my HTML is loaded. `$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#formulario-devolucion-redsys').submit();   }); `
This causes the user to eventually be redirected to URL_OK or URL_NO_OK.

However, if I only use PHP it seems that this is not possible for some reason I do not know